# Casio - Basic programming

Tags: basic, calculator, days

It's a bit urgent... ;)

Someone i know have a Casio calculator (FX-9750 / Grahp35+).

There is in the menu a functionnality TVM with "Days Calculation" that permits to know the number of days between 2 dates.

I have to program for this calculator something very quick but i don't know how to do... i don't know so much about casio programming...

Is it possible to call that TVM -> Days Calculation function inside a program?
I can't find any information about that on google...
Downloaded some casio manuals but i don't see anything about days calculation...

Please help meee :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't call an existing program from CASIO BASIC. I tried finding a way to do that myself, but that was a long time ago with an older calculator, so things could be different now. Still, I couldn't find anything on the internet. In other words, it seems like you would have to implement it yourself.

[Here](http://www.casiocalc.org/?showtopic=2448) is a tutorial that might be of help for the general programming.

[Here](http://forums.applenova.com/showthread.php?t=20321) is a thread about doing what you wanted in Java that might be helpful (to show the approach to take).

[Here](http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-1587/Computing-difference-dates-2.htm) is one in C.

Note that you might be able to download a CASIO SDK and write the program in C, if you find that the BASIC dialect is not up to the task. I do not know if your situation permits that, though, nor if such an SDK is available for your particular model.

If you run into trouble I suggest you post a new question.

EDIT: [This programming manual from CASIO](http://support.casio.com/pdf/004/fx9750g_ch19.pdf) seems to confirm that it is not possible to do what you wanted, and might serve as a good reference should you choose to implement it yourself. It was made for the FX-9750GII.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure how to do it, but for starters:
1. [Calculator Games and Programs](http://www.ehow.com/how_7383197_program-casio-calculator.html) (some have source code too)
2. [How to program casio calc](http://cabbresson.tripod.com/Casio/CasioIndex.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the TWM functions are available from Casio BASIC. Days_Prd() gives the difference between two dates.

```
 Days_Prd(MM1, DD1, YYYY1, MM2, DD2, YYYY2)
```

(A full function reference is available in the manual downloadable from casio and maybe a CD you got with the calculator).